# Material is not translucid anymore

Tags: rendering, materials

Following the coffee tutorial, managed to get it working, but now, all of the sudden it seems that part of the liquid is not behaving the right way, anyone know what might be the issue here?

**Old Version**
[image: Old Version]

**Current (not properly rendered, but you can see the liquid problem)**
[image]

Blender File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hXLEOCWLCKjAbXKdkr0q7BzOxh2g480f/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you [share your .blend file](https://pasteall.org/blend/)?

Comment: Hey @AlexisKing, the blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hXLEOCWLCKjAbXKdkr0q7BzOxh2g480f/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normals on your cup object are flipped inside out. You can see this by selecting the “Face Orientation” viewport overlay, which displays the front side of faces in blue and the back side in red:

[image]

To fix this, in Edit Mode, select all your cup’s faces, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals so they point outside the mesh. This fixes the rendering issue.

Comment: Yep. Definitely the problem. I did the same and it works now.

Comment: Awesome thanks @Alexis King, it fixed